# "ORA-22835: Buffer too small for CLOB to CHAR or BLOB to RAW conversion (actual: 4003, maximum: 4000)"

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to migrate data from oracle db to sql server db.
I am getting this error.
Is there a fix to this issue.

using To_char(column)

Comment: There are thousands of way how to migrate data from Oracle to SQL Server. Please be more specific how you're trying to do it. Name the tools you're using and add the code and commands you're using to the questions.

Comment: I am using to_char to covert a column value in sql developer

Comment: Your question has already three (of 5) requests to close it. To prevent its closing, provide far more and specific context about what you want to achieve.